# Are hidden passives enabled in ranked games?

Tags: league-of-legends

Since events are disabled in ranked games because of advantages, I wonder if hidden passives are enabled or disabled. Sure the 1 damage less recieved from leonas passive while wearing sunglasses isn't that gamechanging but it still is a small plus.

Comment: No they're not disabled.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could kill a Zyra plant with how much damage that particular passive prevents over the course of an hour-long game..

Answer (score 1):

I believe that not all hidden passives are disabled in ranked. One being Zyra growing slightly larger when being hit by one of Leona's abilities. If it directly affects gameplay though, such as the glasses one, it is disabled, due to being able to survive with one health. :)

Answer (score -2):

Hidden passives are disabled in ranked games. There is a [discussion in the forums](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2683532) about it

Comment: What sources or proof can you provide for this?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! As it stands, while this technically might be the right answer to the question, do you have any source to back this up, considering there is a comment above that states they aren't disabled?

Comment: Really? I thought hidden passives are disabled in ranked games..

Comment: http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2683532

Comment: @Shadowmoor There is no official source in your link, there is just a discussion. What they say is basically "It must be disabled, because it's unfair in high elo". This can be an amazing answer if you could provide videos, tests, official sources (ticket answers by RIOT, moderators text...)

Comment: @Shadowmoor In the discussion you link, even the users are arguing whether it's disabled or not. So what gives?